# select statement pointers required please

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I'm looking for some help or pointers please.

I have one table like so

```
hostname | file  | size
server1  | a.txt | 1050
server2  | a.txt | 1024
server3  | a.txt | 1050
```

how do I go about showing the difference in size for the file in the server2 line ?
how do I compare the 3 lines - do I need plsql for this or can it be done in sql?
oracle 12c database

Thanks for any replies
Dan

Comment: what is your expected results to be precise ?

Comment: Could you specify your desired output?

Comment: I want to search the table and find where there is a difference in the size of one of the files, where the files names are the same, but the servers are not and if there is a difference I want to alert someone, I hope that make sense and thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can simply use RANK function for this.

For your sample data -

```
select hostname, file, size
, rank() over (partition by file order by size) rk
from files;
```

This will give you the data with rank on the size, if there are any records in the query output which have rank > 1 then there is a difference in the file size on different servers.